# How can a new graduate find work when applications require experience?

Tags: job-offer, recruitment, entry-level

I have 3 more weeks until my final exams in undergraduate school. It is the best feeling ever. Basically I'm in an electrical engineering program, and most of the time I spend in school is just studying and no work experience (like real experience in the engineering world).

I feel anxious and scared about what will happen to me after graduation.
How am I supposed to find work when most job ads require experience?

So I need a job but the job requires work experience. (Sweet paradox.) How?

Comment: There is not recruiting program at you school.  Get on job boards and start applying.  Create a LinkedIn account

Comment: Also don't be afraid apply to jobs that list a small amount of experience in their requirements, I'd say three years or less.  Your resume can easily be eliminated if that's a hard requirement, so it's not much wasting much time for the recruiters if any, but it's pretty common for recruiters to consider people with less experience than listed in the ad, as long as it's not a huge discrepancy.

Comment: @mkk Are you based in the US? 3 more weeks before final exam is very late to try to get an offer. You don't need experience for entry-level work.

Comment: Look for companies that are recruiting new graduates, rather than looking at job adverts that are asking for experience you don't have.

Comment: Up vote this question because it is a very real perception for the new college graduates. I am a senior in Mechanical Engineering at a major university (by no means tier-1, but definitely respected). However, because of mandatory co-op, I have about 1.5 years of engineering work experience, which is helpful.

On the subject of LinkedIn, I would have to say that I find its matching algorithms quite poor. It routinely sends me job postings for mid-career software engineering team managers, postings which require 7-10+ years experience (I'm 22).

Comment: There's some peril to doing nothing but study, pass your courses and graduate in the 2016 job climate. The internship has become the new entry-level job and the entry-level job has become the new 1-3yr experience required.

For this very reason I'd urge anyone going into college to take full advantage of internships, co-ops, research with faculty and the like. Otherwise, you will find that it's difficult to land something that throws you into using your degree immediately.

Answer (score 3):

Many entry level jobs don't require experience. You may be able to find a placement through your school. It's a good place to check anyway.

Also the school will be more in tune with local availability, much more so than random strangers on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

A few ways to find a new job (as a recent grad and with no experience).

1: Use online websites. There are plenty of sites where you can post your resume to a profile. Employers have job listings they post with keywords and you will be notified if you match any of those. You can apply through the site and hope for the best. I've used LinkedIn but there are many others.

2: Use your school. Most school have advisers that can help you find opportunities through alumni or other contacts. My school has a job fair every fall and spring where companies come and set-up to look for new-grads to hire. See if your school has either of those resources.

3: Use your connections. I have my current position due to a friend who graduated before me. He left behind an internship that I was qualified for and highly recommended me. Having a connection is a great way to get a job, even if they want some experience. Being recommended by someone who knows the job and that has a good reputation in a company can go far.

Also, find a part-time job elsewhere even if it's not in your major. Having work on your resume is better than nothing, even if it's not in your major. You can still get experience and find ways to apply what you've studied to your job and use that experience in interviews.

All of these are personal experience. I don't graduate for another couple of months but I have already found a few options myself. The expectation is that they won't all pan out, but you just have to find one that does and go from there. Just remember that the chances of a job just falling into your lap aren't very high. You have to go out and find it!

Answer (score 0):

if you are in the US, apply to the government agencies, federal, state and local. They have a quota to fill from recent graduates I believe and be ready to invest at least a couple of years there, without blowing your brains out on the 3rd day :)

Consider going for an advanced degree, say masters, while doing work for the school you are graduating from.

Volunteer at large, multinational organizations like peace corp or something without borders. It gives you not only experience but also International exposure.

Do part time freelance work and don't be choosy. I am an electrical engineer myself,but I am in computer systems administration over 20 years. I stumbled into it and realized I loved it more than dinking with resistors, capacitors and later on SMD components etc. Your education is just a start for your career, not the determining factor.

Good luck.